# New to github. Fork or branch?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I'm new to github. I just downloaded the Windows GUI github version. I want to contribute to someone's project. Should I fork the original repo to my repo and start from there or should I branch off from the original repo? How do I merge it back to the original repo later? How to do this on the GUI or do I need to use Git shell?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the original author lets you push to his repo, you won't be allowed to do it. The usual process to contribute to a project you don't own is to:

- create a fork of the repo
- clone the fork you've just created to work on it locally
- create a branch to add your contribution
- add commits to this branch
- push it to your forked repo on github
- send a pull request to the original repo on github so that the author can fetch the branch from your repo, test it, and integrate it if he likes it.

This is explained when you click on [the giant *3 - Fork a repository* link](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) on Github's home page

Comment: Hello, may you explain for what create a branch on step 3? I use branches only for something special or personal. Not for things I want to contribute to upstream.

Comment: Can my teammates use and commit to my fork repo? I want to know about step 3 too. So I should tell my teammates to branch off of my fork repo?

Comment: It's generally a good practice to have one branch per topic. This allows working on several topics in parallel, creating a pull request for each of them, and having the original author accept one topic and refusing another.

Comment: @learntosucceed: yes, by adding them as collaborators: https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator